# best MySQL model to upload 4 different sizes of an image

Tags: php, image

I’m working on a project where the main focus are photos. I want to upload 4 different versions of the same image.

Because of the nature of the project, images need to be optimal and therefore uploaded in the best quality possible (best quality/size ratio). I will use Photoshop to create the best possible quality/size version of the 4 images. In other words, I won't use PHP to resize images at upload time.

For all 4 images, the **title** and **description** are the same, as the **date** the images were uploaded. Every image will have their own **width** and **height** attribute (so as to help the browser when outputting the image in html)...

I came up with the following model:

```
image (image_id, title, desc, filename_s, filename_s_width, filename_s_height, filename_m, filename_m_width, filename_m_height, filename_l, filename_l_width, filename_l_height, filename_xl, filename_xl_width, filename_xl_height, uploaded)
```

Then, thinking that the above model would not scale very much in the future, I’ve thought of the following model:

```
image (image_id, title, desc, uploaded)
imagesize (size_id, size)
image_version (id, image_id, filename, width, height, size_id)
```

There is also the 3 model, which consist of uploading the main image and keep a record in the database. And for the versions of that main image, to append the words ‘_small’, ‘_medium’, ‘_large’, ‘_xlarge’ to the filename. But, i won’t be able to have a record of the width and height of the version images (just the main one) (wich i really want). So, maybe that model is not the best... or maybe it is...

I thought I would ask before I started working the project. I want to start in a good foot and have a solid foundation.

Am i on the right path? Is the second model the one you would use? **Is there a better model out there that i should know about ?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second model is the better one.

The only tweak I might make to this model is to separate the `filename` attribute into basename and suffix and to get rid of the unnecessary id on `image_version`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE imagesizes (
    id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    size VARCHAR NOT NULL COMMENT 'e.g. small, large, thumbnail, original, etc',
    suffix VARCHAR NOT NULL COMMENT 'e.g. _s, _l, _t, or nothing for no suffix',
    UNIQUE KEY suffix (suffix),
    UNIQUE KEY size (size)
);

CREATE TABLE images (
    id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    basename VARCHAR NOT NULL COMMENT 'the base name of the image. Add suffixes to get a filename',
    title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    desc VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    uploaded_on DATETIME NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY basename (basename)
);

CREATE TABLE imagefiles (
    image_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    imagesize_id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    width INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    height INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (image_id, imagesize_id),
    KEY imagesize_idx (imagesize_id),
    CONSTRAINT image FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES images (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT imagesize FOREIGN KEY (imagesize_id) REFERENCES imagesizes (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

You may then get the filename like so:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(image.basename, imagesizes.suffix) AS filename
FROM images INNER JOIN imagefiles ON images.id=imagefiles.id
INNER JOIN imagesizes ON imagefiles.imagesize_id=imagesizes.id;
```

For the ordinary case, you should probably wrap this in a view and query the view instead:

```sql
CREATE VIEW imagelist AS 
SELECT images.id AS id, images.basename AS basename, images.title AS title, images.desc AS desc, 
images.uploaded_on AS uploaded_on, imagefiles.width AS width, imagefiles.height AS height, imagesizes.id AS size_id, 
imagesizes.size AS size, imagesizes.suffix AS suffix, 
CONCAT(imagefiles.basename, imagesizes.suffix) AS filename;
```

Comment: i was talking about the third model... the one were i keep a record of the original image and use suffixes for the versions..

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go with the second. It allows for flexibility in *which* sizes are available without restricting *how many*.

Comment: i think i'm on the right path... 2nd model seems to be a good one

Answer (score 1):

Please, too, consider storing *one* image, then resizing it on-the-fly with a tool like ImageMagick:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: Considered, and rejected. "I will use Photoshop to create ... the 4 images."

Comment: Although OP does not consider it as an option, this is a very, _very_ good option for someone who is open to options. I've created quite a few websites with galleries and use on-demand image sizing. And when the client says "sorry, but the layout has changed (again!), we need wide screen photos in headers, 200x150 thumbnails, 400x300 mediums, ...", my answer is "no problem".

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - you can use whatever you want to "create" the images.  I'm suggesting just *storing* it once, then resizing it on the fly.  And ImageMagick happens to be very good at dynamically resizing images.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

After you upload the images, you can get the image dimensions by using the `getimagesize` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Guess that will be the easiest, and give you all the flexibility you wanted.

Comment: I think he's answering your question at this point: But, i won’t be able to have a record of the width and height of the images (wich i really want)

Comment: I know how to get the size and the other meta data for an uploaded photo... the point i was trying to make is that if i use the third model, i wont have the width and height of the other version of the image, just the main one...